# How to publish a .Net Core lambda function using TeamCity

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, teamcity

I work on a .Net Core solution in which we just added .Net Core lambdas.
The newly created lambdas are all set, including the aws-lambda-tools.json.

All I have left to do is to automatically publish those lambdas using TeamCity.
(Continuous deployment is already set on TC for the rest of the solution)
Also I'd rather not update a TC build step every time we add a new Lambda.

How can I setup TC to automatically publish all lambdas?
Shall I use the .Net CLI or are there any plugin to help me configure this step?

Answer (score 7):

Finally, I opted for a very simple powershell script at the root of the solution, that deploys all the projects whose aws-lambda-tools-defaults are set:

```
$lambdaProfile = "aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json"

$solutionFolder = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName;
$lambdaFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $solutionFolder -File -Recurse aws-lambda-tools-defaults*.json | ForEach-Object {$_.DirectoryName } | Select-Object  -uniq

forEach ($lambdaFolder in $lambdaFolders)
{
    Write-Output "Deploying following lambda: $lambdaFolder"
    Write-Output "with profile: $lambdaProfile"
    Set-Location $lambdaFolder
    dotnet lambda deploy-function -cfg $lambdaProfile
    Set-Location $solutionFolder
}
```

Then just execute this script in a specific build step on TeamCity,

Comment: Thanks it saved my time, but this code working locally but through teamcity its not working below is the error assumed-role/<teamcity role name> is not authorized to perform: lambda.... but can't give access to this role. Is there any way to change role while creating build?